# Different python versions both os and pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I am running on Ubuntu 18.04 and using Pycharm 2020.1. My system using Python version 3.7.6 and Pycharm using 3.6. And this makes conflicts.

```
$ python --version
Python 3.7.6

$ ls /usr/bin/python*
/usr/bin/python   /usr/bin/python2.7  /usr/bin/python3.6   /usr/bin/python3m
/usr/bin/python2  /usr/bin/python3    /usr/bin/python3.6m
```

I tried to change python interpreter but not showing in the list. What can I do for using same version both os and pycharm?

[image]

Comment: It appears "python" is mapped to /usr/bin/python, if you select that and check the version from within pycharm what do you get?

Comment: when I select /usr/bin/python, it gets python version 3.6

Comment: Run "python3 --version" at terminal to check it returns 3.7.6 and try using that.

Comment: it returns 3.7.6. but how can I use this version in pycharm? Or shoul I use 3.6 in os?

Comment: Try picking python3 from the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to choose System Interpreter option not Virtual Environment.

However, is highly not recommended.